# Flex 4 List Component itemRendererFunction Data Adding Sequence

Tags: list, flex4, itemrenderer

I have a list with an itemRendererFunction and I'm adding my data through different renderers but my data's adding sequence is very important. But when I run my app, my data's sequence is random. How can I make it's sequence as it is in my ArrayList(dataProvider)?

My list:

```
<s:List id="calendarList" itemRendererFunction="myItemRendererFunction"
        width="500"
        verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="on">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

And my renderer function:

```
private var eventItemRenderer:IFactory = new ClassFactory(EventItemRenderer);
private var noEventItemRenderer:IFactory = new ClassFactory(NoEventRenderer);

private function myItemRendererFunction(item:Object):IFactory
                {
                    var hasEvent:Boolean = (item.event);
                    trace(item.date, item.event)
                    if (hasEvent)
                    {
                        return eventItemRenderer;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return noEventItemRenderer;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is it possible to clarify it any further? You seem to be saying that the List component is not rendering the elements in the same order that they appear in the ArrayList. But that's not possible -- the List component should always render the items in the same order as they appear in the dataProvider (ArrayList).

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's possible you've ran into one of those classic "itemRenderer recycling" bugs that we, as Flex developers, create every so often. However, that bug is usually only noticed after you scroll the list. Does this problem happen the first time the list items are rendered or only after scrolling?

Comment: I think that's the problem. The first datas on the list are in order but when I scroll down, other datas are coming random. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: OK, the itemRenderer recycling issue is caused by your itemRenderer code. Can you show us the code for one of your renderers? You might also try searching for "itemRenderer recycling" ... Note that in Flex 4 and earlier renderers were not recycled when you used an itemRendererFunction, but Adobe fixed that in Flex 4.1 (or later).

Comment: I just realize that in my renderer functions, instead of overriding set data function, I was setting my data in renderer's initialize event. So I think it wasn't an itemRenderer recycling but my mistake :D. Thanks for your answers. (My problem solved after overriding set data func. in my renderers)